# Iterating over an array that has been passed by reference in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I wish to write an print array function in c. I have herd when you pass an array to a c function via reference it passes a pointer to the first element. I am assuming that I can increment this pointer to iterate over the array however my program just segfaults.

I would like to know firstly why my program is seg faulting and also what the most idiomatic approach to writing a function like this in c. Thanks in adavnce.

```
void print_array(int *array, int length) {
    int i = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < length; array++) {
        printf("%d\n", *array);
    }
}

int main (int argc, int *argv[]) {
    int test[10] = {0};
    print_array(test, 10);
}
```

Comment: you never increment `i`.

Comment: you are incrementing the pointer into oblivion

Comment: -1 for changing the value of a parameter. In less trivial code, it makes it hard to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is infinite, because `i` in `i < length` never changes; That condition always evaluates true. As a result, you're jumping past the end of the loop. I suggest changing your loop to:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

... or, if you wish to use `array++`, change the condition:

```
for (int *end = array + length; array < end; array++) {
    printf("%d\n", *array);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So *end is the array pointer + length. Am I correct in assuming that when you add an int to a pointer it returns a pointer offset by the added int. So given that array++ points to the next memory block?

Comment: @Stewart s/points to the next memory block/causes array to point to the next int/. `array + 1` points to `array[1]`, and `array++` is shorthand for `array = array + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void print_array(int *array, int length) {
    int i = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Since `i` is your loop control variable (it's in the loop condition), you need to increment it to avoid an infinite loop. And using the `[]` notation is much easier to grasp for someone at your level than trying to increment the pointer manually.